# hbase store multiple values for one key

Tags: hash, hbase

I'm new in hbase and want to save multiple values for a row key in hbase.
Is this possible?
For example

```
RowKey | Values

1212   | 12

1213   | 12, 13, 14
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is possible. You can think of HBase data model as several nested maps.
`Map<RowKey, Map<ColumnFamilyKey, <Map<ColumnKey, <Map<Version, Value>>>>`. All kyes, as a value, have type byte arrays, except version which should be long number (64bit integer). The number and values of Column Families should be predefined for table and should not exceed 3-4 due to performance issue. From this you have two variants to store multiples values per row: in different columns or in single column with different versions. Version should be a long number.

Comment: Thank you for this approach. Maybe a concatenation of values is the better solution for my task. Or can I store a array of values?

Comment: Array of values in not very convenient, to add element you should read it and modify it, then save a new version. When you will have a several values in arrays, performance will be suffer, because the amount of data that will be transferred will be exceeded in several times the size of one element.

Comment: You can specify a version or by default it will be java timestamp.

Comment: A okay, that makes sense. Than I use the columns to save it. Is here a problem with the performcance if one row had 2 familys and each of them have 1000 of columns and another row only have one family with one column?